# itemAdded event not firing on bootstrap taginput with typeahead

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, bootstrap-tags-input

I have the following html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i> University</label>
    <input id="university" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

I initialise `taginput` with `typeahead` using ajax prefix like this in my `script.js` file:

```
// When page loads
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Helper function to initialise tag input with type ahead bloodhound
    function initTagInput(inputTarget) {
        var targetField = $('input#'+ inputTarget);
        targetField.tagsinput({
            typeaheadjs: {
                name: inputTarget,
                displayKey: 'name',
                valueKey: 'name',
                source: new Bloodhound({
                    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
                    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                    prefetch: {
                        url: '/ajax/load-dropdown-options/'+ inputTarget,
                        filter: function(list) {
                            return $.map(list, function(optionName) {
                                return { name: optionName };
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }).ttAdapter()
            },
            freeInput: false
        });
        targetField.on('itemAdded', initSearch);
    }

    // Initialise tag input fields
    initTagInput('university');
    // todo other fields

    // Method to init search (triggered by tag input)
    function initSearch()
    {
        console.log('todo search');
    }
});
```

This works to the point the taginput with typeahead working together:

[image] ==> [image]

As you can see, this has worked. However, the `itemAdded` event is not firing as the console is empty (as per above test):

[image]

Any idea what might be wrong? is this not working because I am initializing it within a helper function?